# psexec in c sharp not work when use variable

Tags: c#, session, psexec

trying to run this command in c sharp ,the first command with (session id var)not work
the second command when put -i 1 working .. how to fix this ?

```
string showinfo = (@"psexec -d -h -i"+session_id+" -u qa -p 12 \\" + ping_ip + @" C:\Users\qa\Desktop\vdbench50407\Scripts\vd.bat");

//string showinfo = (@"psexec -d -h -i 1 -u qa -p 12 \\" + ping_ip + @" C:\Users\qa\Desktop\vdbench50407\Scripts\vd.bat");

proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(showinfo);
```

Thanks,

Comment: You probably miss a space between `-i` and your `session_id`.

Comment: You should really be a little more elaborate than "not work" and "working".  What isn't working?  Also, you should take not of the edit that was made to your question.  Do you see that it now shows your code as code, and not just a mass of text.  I did that with the `{}` button (which formats the selected lines of code as code.

Comment: By the way, you are less likely to make an error like the one that @SGKoishi points out if you use _Interpolated strings_: `var showinfo = $@"psexec -d -h -i {session_id} -u qa -p 12 \{ping_ip} C:\Users\qa\Desktop\vdbench50407\Scripts\vd.bat";`

Comment: @Flydog57: the double backslash in the post is not within a verbatim string but in your interpolated version,  it is. Whether or not the OP meant just one backslash character, they're not the same. Heck, that may even be part of the problem, as the commented version does have it within a verbatim string.

Comment: One other thing to note (so that you don't drive future maintenance programmers nuts) is that when you concatenate three strings together on a line, don't mix and match _@"verbatim strings"_ with _"regular strings"_.  Apparently @madreflection has much sharper eyes than I do

Comment: @Flydog57 , thanks friend , still not work ..
`var showinfo = $@"psexec -d -h -i {session_id} -u qa -p 12 \{ping_ip} C:\Users\qa\Desktop\vdbench50407\Scripts\vd.bat"`

Comment: This is the full command used after run : 
`var showinfo = "psexec -d -h -i 1 -u qa -p 12 \\10.0.59.169 C:\\Users\\qa\\Desktop\\vdbench50407\\Scripts\\vd.bat"`
`proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(showinfo);`